# GMock: gtest_filter ignored on Android

Tags: android, c++, googletest, googlemock

I am running some unit tests using GTest/GMock on Android. I have noticed that it ignores my argument of `--gtest_filter=MyTestCase.MyTest` - all of my tests run no matter what I put in the filter. I've made sure that it gets passed in to `InitGoogleMock`.

Has anyone managed to use `--gtest_filter` when running their tests on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved, `--gtest_filter` was my first argument, but GTest parses arguments from index 1 rather than 0, as argument 0 is expected to be the executable name in unix land :).